# Different Numpy Array Shapes Returned For Similar Value Slicing

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy array as below:

```
mat = np.arange(1,26).reshape(5,5)
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
```

From here, if I want to slice out the 2,7,12 values I see I can do it two ways:
`mat[0:3,1]`
which returns
`array([ 2,  7, 12])`
or
`mat[:3,1:2]`
which returns

```
array([[ 2],
       [ 7],
       [12]])
```

I am not sure how the same slicing concept fetches the same values, but with different shape.
Any help understanding this will be great.

Comment: `x:y` will extract a range, just `x` a value. When extracting a range the dimensionality is and has to be maintained.

Comment: So in the 'row' or the 'column', in whichever position of the slice I am using a range, that axis's dimensionality will be maintained in the result? Am I understanding this right?

Comment: Those don't look similar.  One has a scalar `1`, the other a slice, `1:2`.    Do those produce the same thing when applied to a list?

Comment: Say if I want to extract the 2,7,12 ,these three values from the matrix, those are the only two slicing which can get this data. My problem is understanding how the dimensionality changes with how I slice. In once case, the shape returned is a (3, 1) array, and in another I get a (3,) array.

Comment: Have yiou actually read numpy indexing docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy extends the python concept of slicing in N dimensions as you can read in the official [Numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

It is easier to understand in 1D. Consider a list of integers `A=[1,2,3]`, `A[1]` will return the integer `2` while `A[1:2]` will return a list containing one item `[2]`.

It is similar in 2D with Numpy arrays,in your example `mat[0:3,1]` returns an array of integers while `mat[0:3,1:2]` returns an array of arrays, each one containing a single integer.

Comment: Thank you, the 1D example clarified things!